# Wireless Problems with ASUS U56E laptop

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, asus, intel-wireless

I have an ASUS U56E Laptop that after a while of being turned on will loose wireless connection and give me an error. I have looked around for a solution (e.g. if there is a driver that I need to install) but have had no luck. This is happening on a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.10.

[image: Error Message]

The connection will drop sometimes and give me this error. Or when starting my laptop, It will simply just not work at all and I will still get the same error.

Hopefully this helps as well:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b5)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev b5)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev b5)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev b5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM65 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N + WiMAX 6150 (rev 67)
03:00.0 USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1042 SuperSpeed USB Host Controller
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR8151 v2.0 Gigabit Ethernet (rev c0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this:

`options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=N`

to `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf`.

Use the command `sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf`.

Try running the following if that doesn't work:

`sudo service network-manager restart`

If this still doesn't work, try

`sudo apt-get purge network-manager`

then

`sudo apt-get install network-manager`

Answer (score 0):

I had significant issues with wifi on an Intel 8265.
The solution was to disable power management on the device.
Perhaps that will help in your case.

Create: `/etc/network/if-up.d/wifi-powerman-off`
Enable: `chmod +x /etc/network/if-up.d/wifi-powerman-off`
Note: Replace **<< interface name >>** with your wifi device name (e.g. `wlp1s0`)

`wifi-powerman-off`:

```
#!/bin/sh
IWCONFIG=/sbin/iwconfig
WLAN_IFACE=<<interface name>>
if [ ! -x $IWCONFIG ]; then
    exit 1
fi
if [ "$IFACE" = $WLAN_IFACE ]; then
    $IWCONFIG $IFACE power off
fi
```

Comment: I don't understand why this answer is downvoted. Upvote from me. Sometimes wireless doesn't work properly because of power saving bullshit, it's true, happened to me.

Comment: I admit I laughed @Saibot. I understand how it many not have been the solution to the specific issue but I thought it was a valuable bit of info. Thanks for the karma.